# Python decorator question

Tags: python, decorator

decorator 1:

```
def dec(f):
    def wrap(obj, *args, **kwargs):
        f(obj, *args,**kwargs)
    return wrap
```

decorator 2:

```
class dec:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
    def __call__(self, obj, *args, **kwargs):
        self.f(obj, *args, **kwargs)
```

A sample class,

```
class Test:
    @dec
    def disp(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(*args,**kwargs)
```

The follwing code works with decorator 1 but not with decorator 2.

```
a = Test()
a.disp("Message")
```

I dont understand why decorator 2 is not working here. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Which part doesn't work?

Comment: a = Test(); a.disp("Message") did not work with decorator 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you decorate with the `dec` class, your `disp` method is no more an instance method, but an instance of class `dec`. So `a.disp` is just a plain member of `Test`, which happens to be callable because it has a `__call__` method, and in the self passed as the first argument of its `f` instance is `"Message"` (it is by no way bound to the "test" instance).

with the decorator function:

```
a = Test()
print a.disp
# disp <bound method Test.wrap of <__main__.Test instance at 0xb739df0c>>
```

with the decorator class:

```
a = Test()
print a.disp
# disp <__main__.dec instance at 0xb739deec>
```

**edit**
That should answer your question far better and clearer than I did:

http://irrepupavel.com/documents/python/instancemethod/